# How should I access methods from a different Model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods, model, controller

I'm rolling my own mini-MVC so that I can better understand the design principles.  Quite early in my project, I need to call a method not directly accessible by one of my controllers.  In terms of best practice,

1. Assuming that my approach below is OK, if I need access to the Rich_Text_Editor_Model, and I just need it for the richTextEditor method, is it better to put it in the method itself, or in the controller's Constructor?
2. Are there any alternative approaches?  (My guess is that I'm going to be running into this concept a bunch of times.)

Thanks!

```
public function richTextEditor($rich_text_editor_id = null) {
    $rich_content_editor_model = new Rich_Text_Editor_Model();
    $rich_text_editor_info = $rich_content_editor_model->getRichTextEditorInfo($rich_text_editor_id);
    if ($rich_text_editor_info) {
    $this->view->rich_text_editor = $rich_text_editor_info['rich_text_editor'];
    }

    $this->view->render("content/rich_text_editor");
}
```

Comment: Model is not a class but a layer. Model does not have methods, because it is an conceptual collection of other structures.

Comment: OK.  I appreciate the correction.  Would it be more correct to ask "What's the best way for a Controller to access a class method that's not a method of that Controller?"